# How do I specifically position JLabels within a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I made a JPanel, which has 6 string JLabels, and one image JLabel. What I need is to be able to position the Jlabel strings somewhere inside of my image JLabel's bounds. I'm pretty sure my problem would be solved if I knew how to resize JLabels.

Some Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("rainbow seizure");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton newCardButton = new JButton("New Card");
        newCardButton.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(panel2));

            JLabel jImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\unkno\\java\\Card1.PNG"));
            Dimension dimension = jImage.getPreferredSize(); // dimensions for me are 72x122

            System.out.println(dimension.width);
            System.out.println(dimension.height);

            JLabel label1 = new JLabel("name");
            label1.setBounds(new Rectangle(dimension.width, dimension.height)); // doesn't do anything :(
            label1.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
            label1.setAlignmentY(Component.TOP_ALIGNMENT);

            JLabel label2 = new JLabel("cost");
            JLabel label3 = new JLabel ("atk");
            JLabel label4 = new JLabel("type");
            JLabel label5 = new JLabel  ("hp");
            JLabel label6 = new JLabel("disc");

            panel2.add(label1);
            panel2.add(label2);
            panel2.add(label3);
            panel2.add(label4);
            panel2.add(label5);
            panel2.add(label6);
            panel2.add(jImage);

            panel.add(panel2);
            frame.revalidate();
        });
        frame.add(newCardButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the image label have to be a label or do you just need the image to display?  You might be better creating a JPanel with the image drawn on the `Graphics` and placing the images on that panel.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, so yes it does

Comment: Why not add to a component that sets the image as that container's background?

Comment: This should show you how, it's not difficult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44703405/paint-image-in-jpanel-using-drawimage

Comment: Swing has a parent/child relationship. If you want the labels displayed on the image then you add the labels to the image. There are two basic ways to do this: 1) paint the image on a panel and then add the labels to the panel using this approach the image can be scaled or 2) use an ImageIcon on a JLable, then set the layout manager of the label and then add the other 6 labels to the label with the Icon. Using this approach the image will always be painted at its original size.